# KEYLEFT not working pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a program and this is the code not working:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYLEFT():
    if event.key == K_LEFT:
        coordsX = coordsX - 1
```

this is the error message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\**********\ControlsTest.py", line 54, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.KEYLEFT():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'KEYLEFT'
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the correct `event.type`

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
```

The event `type` is that a key was pressed, `KEYDOWN`. Then you check *which* key was pressed so you compare the event `key` with the `K_LEFT` key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no field nor event type KEYLEFT. You're looking for  `pygame.KEYDOWN`, which is a variable and not a method, so remove the parentheses.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    ...
```

My suggestion is to use an IDE with code completion, like Eclipse or Sublime, which would make it a lot easier to get the correct names from libraries you're using.

Comment: I'd actually recommend to a beginner not to do so. It's important to have learnt the troubles and issues of not working precisely, if you want to get better at programming. You might not always have the choice to use such IDEs :) But that's just my two cents :)